# When i use highcharts then my DataTable lost his functionality.

Tags: codeigniter, highcharts

I use jquery.dataTables.min.js for Data table..
then i try to use highcharts. but when i put highcharts code in document ready function then dataTable lost his functionality.. such as search box, scroll, design.

$(function() {

```
/*For Highcharts*/  
var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({  
    chart: {  
        renderTo: 'my_chart',  
        type: 'line'  
    },  
    title: {  
        text: 'Monthly National Trend of SOMA-JECT Administration'  
    },  
    xAxis: {  
        categories: ['January', 'February', 'March']  
    },  
    yAxis: {  
        title: {  
            text: 'No. of SOMA-JECT Administration'  
        }  
    },  
    series: [{  
        name: 'Soma-JECT',  
        data: [1, 0, 4]  
    }, {  
        name: 'Sayana PRESS',  
        data: [5, 7, 3]  
    }]  
});  

/*For Data Table*/  
$('#example').DataTable({  
    scrollX: true  
});
```

});

Comment: Any errors in your console? What is the load order of your javascript resources?

Comment: Thanks so much wergeld. resources does not change. i change order of my scripts. highcharts scripts move to bottom of dataTable scripts then everything is ok. thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change order of scripts. highcharts scripts move to bottom of dataTable scripts then may be everything is OK.